# In Battlestar Galatica Pegasus expansion, does the cylon team win if the cylon leader wins?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In the pegasus expansion, these points happen:

1. The cylon players win.
2. The cylon leader reveals his agenda
   and he completed it successfully.

Did both cylons and cylon leader win the game OR did the cylons lose the game and only the leader wins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cylons *and* the Cylon leader win the game, together. The Agenda Card condition indicates which side they favor. They will have another condition which seems counter to their allegiance, but they are predominantly on one side or the other.

From page 10 of the Pegasus rule book:

> Note that Cylon Leaders may win with the humans or the Cylons, as
>   specified by their Agenda Card.